# Hold HttpPostedFileWrapper in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a scenario where my users need to add a photo to my website. So, they use a `<input type="file" />`, they see a little preview, then they have to go to the next page to confirm everything.

I don't want to save the uploaded photo until they submit the confirm form on the confirm page. This is not that same page as the file upload input.

HTML + Razor

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SmallLogo, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SmallLogo, new { type = "file" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
namespace Models.Registration
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Theme
    {
        [NonSerialized]
        private HttpPostedFileBase _SmallLogo;

        [DisplayName("Small Logo: ")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase SmallLogo
        {
            get { return _SmallLogo; }
            set { _SmallLogo = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to post from my controller, but basically, I update the model when  the page (form) is submitted through an HTTP POST. At first, when using debugging, I could hover the model and they would show as `HttpPostedFileWrapper`. Then I changed the model field type to be `HttpPostedFileBase`, but after that I was getting an error about it not being seriablizable.

So then I followed some other posts about creating a private field that is serilizable, then just getting and settings that value. Now when I pause the program after submitting the form, the modal just show null. It's so lame.

If I've left out info that you need to help me, than please ask and I'll get it for you! Help me to help you to help me! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is stateless.

As such, if request 1 uploads the file and you want request 2 to save the file - this is going to be hard.

What you should do, instead, is have request 1 save the file to location 1 ('temp' location). Then request 2 can move the file from location 1 to location 2 ('final' location). Then periodically delete items from location 1 that are old (e.g. last updated a month ago)